# Randomly assign an image to each page in my site?

Tags: php, algorithm, random

I have a 50 page website and a set of 20 images. How can I somewhat randomly assign an image to each page but ensure that each page will always display the same image?

Each page has a slug value, is there a way to hash this into an integer from 1-20 (or any set of numbers)?

Comment: For 50 pages of static content, you may as well do it by hand.

Comment: @Null I agree - especially if, once assigned, it will always be using the same image...

Answer (score 1):

As @Null Set said, if this is static content, then it's simple enough to do it by hand. If, on the other hand, the page is being dynamically generated, then perhaps it's worth it to keep this information in a database. You could have an `images` table where each record has an auto-incrementing id and a URL for the image. The db table that holds your page information could then hold a foreign key to the relevant `images` table record.

Any new pages could be assigned an image by using your databases equivalent to [`RAND()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) to pick a random record from the `images` table to use (though beware that for MySQL, `RAND()` quickly runs into performance issues - 20 records is fine, but if you start adding a lot more, you'll have to [start optimizing](http://akinas.com/pages/en/blog/mysql_random_row/) a bit more).

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost certain you could use body id="page" to define which image will be displayed using a selector.

More or less the same way you would do an active state for a nav using css sprites.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like `$count = md5($str) % 20;`, the page image will remain same if page `str` does not change. If you change the content, then image will change.

PHP people usually include the total page from headers, footers, and other parts, but if that is not true or contents is separated in some file, then you can also use `md5_file` function.

Comment: And if you throw a fixed "salt" into the hash too, then you can re-randomize everything without changing the per-page data you're hashing, by choosing a new salt.

Comment: @Steve Jessop Yes. Also if you throw in offset before taking the modulus, you can tilt sequence value for all the images `(md5($str+$salt)+$offset) % 20;`.